# How to Draw UML Diagram for NoSql Like MongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, uml, erd, nosql

I would like to know that can i draw UML diagrams for my web application which has back end  Mongodb?

Or is there any other diagrams for NoSql?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modeling Tool for NOSQL Databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22835089/modeling-tool-for-nosql-databases)

Answer (score 6):

I found a similar answer online, perhaps this will help:

> NoSQL databases approach modelling from a different point of view generally. NoSQL modelling usually begins with asking questions on how the data in the database is going to be queried, so the main modelling is 'what are the list of questions that I want to ask of my database', whereas with SQL databases, modelling usually is a function of what data you have, that is, what answers I have already.
>
> Once you have a list of questions, you then need to design a model
>   that will answer those questions via the NoSQL database. To model it,
>   I typically use Creately which is an online tool for visually
>   representing models of various kinds.
>
> Another method could be to represent your NoSQL model in JSON format
>   and then use the wonderful D3.js javascript library to create a
>   data-driven document. See [this](http://d3js.org/) website for more details and the
>   templates available to visually represent your model.
>
> Hope it helps.

Comment: so with the help of creately tool i can draw class diagram  but what about   use case diagram and sequence diagram

Comment: @nilayjoshi Use any UML modeling tool and start modeling.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an interesting way to do it:
https://dataedo.com/tutorials/how-to-create-er-diagram-for-mongodb

[image]

Using DrawIO to represent this is easy
How it Helps

Comment: What is the difference then? It looks just like an ERD we draw for RDB.

Comment: Did you see nested object in entities? Like "IMDb.rating", usually, this should be another table relationship